# How to divide array in different consecutive sequences

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How to divide this array:- [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15] into two different arrays with one set of consecutive sequences in one array and another set of consecutive in another array.

for eg : array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15] 
 
Desired output  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] and [12, 13, 14, 15]

The array should split into a number of consecutive sequences present in the array. If there are 3 consecutive sequences then the array should split into 3 different arrays with consecutive values and so on.

Another example = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4 5, 14, 15, 16, 22, 23, 24, 25] 
 
Desired output  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and [14, 15, 16] and [22, 23, 24, 25]

```
let arrnew = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15] 
   let arr2 = []

for (let j = 0; j < arrnew.length; j++) {
    if (arrnew[j + 1] - 1 === arrnew[j]) {
        arr2.push(arrnew[j])
    }
}
```

Tried this but not working.

Comment: Loop over the array, checking whether the current element is 1+ the previous element. If it is, append the element to a new sub-array. If not, start a new sub-array.

Comment: Did you use your browser's devtools inspect facility to see if there are any errors? Try going through your loop with a small array of length say 2. what happens when gets to 1 in your for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]
var result = []

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
        result.push([arr[0]])
    } else if (arr[i] != arr[i-1] + 1) {
        result.push([arr[i]])
    } else {
        tmp = result[result.length - 1]
        tmp.push(arr[i])
        result[result.length - 1] = tmp
    }
}

console.log(result) // [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] ]
```

Here we loop through `arr`. For the first element, the only thing we need to do is append to `result` a new array with the first number.

Now, for every number after the first one, if the current number is not equal to the previous number + 1, we need to append a new array to `result` that contains the current number. Otherwise, we simply append the current number to the last array in `result`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked...do you think this can be done with inbuilt methods?

Comment: @ApoorvSharma Unfortunately no, this is a unique and common programming problem, so I don't think that there is a method in the standard library of JS to handle that.

Comment: Sorry to bother but please can you explain me the last part of the if else ladder ? i dint understand what you did

Comment: 1. Save the last element (array) of result to a variable called tmp. 2. Add the current number to tmp. 3. Replace the last element of result with tmp.

Also if my answer to your question helped, could you please mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 22, 23, 24, 25];
const canSplit = (arr = []) => {
    const count = arr.reduce((acc, num) => {
      acc[num] = (acc[num] || 0) + 1
      return acc
    }, {})
    const needed = {}
  
    for (const num of arr) {
      if (count[num] <= 0) {
        continue
      }
      count[num] -= 1
      if (needed[num] > 0) {
        needed[num] -= 1
        needed[num + 1] = (needed[num + 1] || 0) + 1
      } else if (count[num + 1] > 0 && count[num + 2]) {
        count[num + 1] -= 1
        count[num + 2] -= 1
        needed[num + 3] = (needed[num + 3] || 0) + 1
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
}
console.log(canSplit(arr));
```